# How can AWS EC2 instance be connected to via SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am unable to connect to an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance via ssh using github action.

This is my github action workflow

```
name: Testing

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  test:
    ...

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to UAT
    needs: integration-test

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Deploy to EC2 instance
        run: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.AWS_INSTANCE_IP }} "cd /var/www/html/api/uat && git pull && composer install --no-dev && php artisan migrate:seed && php artisan optimize"
```

The `deploy` job runs until the `Deploy to EC2 instance` with this error:

```
Run ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no *** "cd /var/www/html/api/uat && git pull && composer install --no-dev && php artisan migrate:seed && php artisan optimize"
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no *** "cd /var/www/html/api/uat && git pull && composer install --no-dev && php artisan migrate:seed && php artisan optimize"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ***
    AWS_REGION: ***
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
runner@***: Permission denied (publickey).
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the script specifying the keypair to use with SSH? It is normally specified with `-i keypair.pem`.

Comment: That's not an ideal way to provide AWS credentials to your EC2 instance. First, you're using IAM User credentials which are long-lived (you should be using an IAM Role). Second, EC2 has a way for you to configure role-based credentials (see "instance profile") so you don't need to pass them directly.

Comment: @jarmod I would love to know more about how to do this and I guess its similar to what was done here https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials?tab=readme-ov-file#overview

Can you share more on it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I actually thought about it then thought against it since I was passing IAM credentials. What is the best practice to use?

Comment: @Mena: your EC2 instance has its own IAM credentials, available to the applications that run inside it from the [metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html). These credentials are for the role attached to the instance. All AWS client libraries (including PHP) look at this endpoint if you don't specify the credentials explicitly, so most applications "just work" on EC2.

Comment: IAM credentials are used to make API calls to AWS services. Instances running Linux, however, require a keypair to authenticate SSH connections. These are two completely separate authentication methods. (Unless you are using EC2 Instance Connect.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so its safe to store the keypair on github secrets, right?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You don't seem to be providing any credentials to ssh.

You need to do something to this effect:

1. Save your ssh private key in a secret
2. Pass the secret to your docker image in an enviroment variable.
3. Save it to a temp file inside the container: `TEMP_KEY=$(mktemp); echo "$SSH_SECRET" > "$TEMP_KEY"`
4. Remove non-owner permissions on the key file: `chmod go-rwx "$TEMP_KEY"`
5. Pass it as a parameter to ssh: `ssh -i "$TEMP_KEY" …`

Alternatively, you can use the action [appleboy/ssh-action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) and just pass the secret in its parameter `key`